# Not able get element using xpath following-sibling

Tags: xpath

I am not able select xpath using following sibling. It says element not found

tried below syntax,

1. `//x/y[contains(text(),"Status"]/following-sibling::/x/y`
2. `//x/y[contains(text(),"Status"]/following-sibling::/x/y/text()`
3. `//x/y[contains(text(),"Status"]/../x/y`

This is what my HTML code looks like,

```
<X>
<y> Status </y>
</x>
<x>
    <y> ACTIVE</y>
</x>
```

None of above syntax gives ACTIVE as output. It throws element not found error. Can anyone help me to formulate proper syntax to get value.

Comment: The `y` element does not have any siblings.

Comment: is there any other method with which i can get the similar results? For 1st record (Status) is the label and 2nd record (ACTIVE) is value for it. I have most of tables built like that in our application.

Comment: I don't know XPath, but it's probably something like `//x/y[contains(text(),"Status"]/../following-sibling::x/y`.

Comment: Thanks melpomene. It did not worked. Throwing "It should be an element" error.

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

This expression

```
(//y)[2]
```

Outputs:

```
ACTIVE
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I want to take value based on the previous record which is label for me.

Comment: @RameshBabuMS - what do you mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```xml
//x[contains(y,"Status")]/following-sibling::x/y/text()
```

Like mentioned in a comment, `y` doesn't have any siblings; only `x` does. Select the `x` that contains a `y` with "Status" and then select the following `x` sibling (and child `y`'s text()).